# Map inside map in react ( one is local array of images and the other is title from json )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

As being designer and novice to react, I developed code in which local array is displaying as image and json data as title. Titles are working fine but images are not displaying and showing all of arrays in src attribute.

I have used Axios.get() to fetch data from the server.

I am missing out in logic somewhere while developing map inside map. I would be grateful for getting help.

EDIT : **I want one image with one title.**

**CommonMeds.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CommonMeds.scss';
import MedSection from '../../Components/MedSection/MedSection';
import Axios from 'axios';

class CommonMeds extends Component {
    state = {
        MedTitle: [],
        TitleImg: [
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_1.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_2.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_3.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_4.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_5.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_6.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_7.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_8.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_9.svg') },
        { imageSrc: require('../../../../images/medstype_10.svg') },
    ]

};

componentDidMount() {  
    const medInfo = Axios.get('URL OF JSON DATA');
    medInfo.then( response => {
        this.setState({MedTitle: response.data.result});
    });
}

render() {
    const Meds = this.state.MedTitle.map(med => {
        const imglable = this.state.TitleImg.map(src => {
            return src.imageSrc;
        })
        return <MedSection
            Title={med.medicationCategory}
            src = {imglable} 
            />;
    });

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className="text-left">Common Medicines with Categories</h3>
            <hr />
            {Meds}
        </div>
    );
}

}

export default CommonMeds;
```

**MedSection.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './MedSection.scss';
import MedicineList from '../MedicineList/MedicineList';


const MedSection = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="col-12">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 px-0">
                    <div className="c-medsimg-box py-4 px-2">
                        <img src={props.src} alt="Medication Type Icon" className="img-fluid" />
                        <h5 className="mt-3" key={props.key}>{props.Title}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    <div className="h-100 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <ul className="c-medslist-ul pl-0 mb-0">
                            <MedicineList />
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MedSection;
```

Comment: For every `MedTitle` you are creating a `MedSection` which you give an array `imglable` that contains all images. Do you want to use the first title in `MedTitle` with the first image in `TitleImg`, and so on?

Comment: @Tholle Yes, I want one image with one title. Thank you.

Comment: Great. And will the `MedTitle` array always have the same length as the `TitleImg` array when your request is complete, or can they differ in length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently creating an array of images for each `MedTitle`. You could instead take the entry from `TitleImage` that has the same index as the current `med` in your loop instead.

You can also make it safe by using the `%` operator, so that if your `MedTitle` array is larger than your `TitleImage` array, you will still get an image.

```
const Meds = this.state.MedTitle.map((med, index) => {
  const src = this.state.TitleImg[index % this.state.TitleImg.length].imageSrc;

  return <MedSection Title={med.medicationCategory} src={src} />;
});
```

Comment: Yes, index with '%' is working perfectly fine. Thanks for this great help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as length of both arrays are same, it will work.
Try using this.

```
const imglable = this.state.TitleImg.map(src => {
       return src.imageSrc;
    })

const Meds = this.state.MedTitle.map((med, index) => {
     return <MedSection
             Title={med.medicationCategory}
              src = {imglable[index]} 
            />;
});
```

Comment: This is also working perfectly. The only missing parameter was "index". It cleared many of my concepts. Thanks for your valuable answer.